# Android app name different from google play name

Tags: android, google-play

Is it allowed to publish android app on Google Play and set one name on Google Play and another name in Application manifest? I know that it can be done, but will Google remove my application because of this?

Egg. I want to call my application on Google play "Green Earth" but on device, I'd like to be called "Red Sun". It can easily be done, but will Google mind? I've tried searching for answer, but had no luck.

Comment: I think there is no problem to keep different app name on Google play store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is entirely possible. I have done the same with my application [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomdoesburg.kooktijden) and haven't had any problems since it was uploaded in October last year. Using a different name in Google Play also allows you to be easier to find for future users, who will often search for the purpose of your app in stead of the app's name.